# How to display thousands of the same mesh with dynamic colors efficiently in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d

I have a single, simple mesh. A cube. It's 50% transparent.

I need to display thousands of them but the color and transparency of each one changes every frame. The entire cube changes color, not just a set of faces. The mesh stays the same and there will be very little (but some) transformation of the cube position.

What I've seen so far is "instancing" but I've only seen that for static items.

How do I show thousands of color changing cubes in OpenGL?

Comment: Instancing would be useless if it were for static items. At minimum, you need a way of conveying separate location for every instance. You can usually tack on other attributes such as color, scale, etc. using whatever technique you used for position. _I know this sounds vague, but there are a lot of instancing techniques (some rely on texture / uniform buffers, others on vertex attributes)._ What version of GL are you targeting here?

Answer (score 3):

Instancing is a potential solution.

What you do is instead of making only the position an instance variable you also make the color one.

One VBO has the total cube mesh.

The other has a sequence of `InstanceData {vec3 position, vec3 color}`

You specify the attributes as:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, instanceBuffer);
glVertexAttribPointer(cubePosLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(InstanceData), (void*)offsetof(position, InstanceData));

glVertexAttribPointer(cubeColorLoc, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(InstanceData), (void*)offsetof(color, InstanceData));
```

And set the `AttributeDivisor` for both `cubePosLoc` and `cubeColorLoc`.

In the vertex shader you then treat these as normal attributes. (add the Cubeposition to the position of the vertex and pass the color on to the fragment shader)

In between each frame you update the `instanceBuffer` with the new location and color.

Answer (score 0):

Set the color (or some other factor representing the color) as a uniform and then incorporate the uniform either you vertex or fragment shader as appropriate.